# Change the width of a Menu using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Anyone tells me how to change the width of a menu using SwiftUI?

I tried using `ViewModifier` but did not change.

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Menu("Options") {
                Button("Option 1") {
                }
                Button("Option 2") {
                }
            }
            .modifier(
                MenuWidthModifier(width: 50)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct MenuWidthModifier: ViewModifier {
    let width: CGFloat
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .frame(width: width)
    }
}
```